# Image Stretch in Unity when using for Sniper Zoom

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to making a sniper zoom using unity. When user zooms i want to show 
Sniper Scope image.

I simple place the image in Unity Image Component.

Here is the image example
[image]

The image stretches like this.
[image: Streached Image]

How can i maintain the aspect ratio. There is once option for  saving the aspect ratio but then it removes background from top and bottom

Comment: Can you show us the ingame setup of the canvas / UI-Image? Have you tried `AspectRationFitter`(http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html) or a `CanvasScaler` (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) on the canvas? (You could use `Reference Resolution` together with a 1.0 bias on `Match Width`)

Comment: do i need to check preserver aspect ratio for this

Comment: Thanks Maximilian it looks like it worked